# Has this function been described/discussed?

Tags: functions

Consider this Cartesian formula for a circle:

$$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$$

which implies

$$y = ±\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$$

It is not a function, since for each value of x, except two, there will be two different values of y.

But now let's introduce this:

$$y = \begin{cases}\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\ \ \ \ \ \ \text{if}\ \ x\in\Bbb Q\\-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\ \ \ \text{if}\ \ x\not\in\Bbb Q\end{cases}$$

Now, this is a function (for each $x$, there is one and only one value of $y$).

A few other properties come to mind:

1. if we attempt to draw it, it is going to be indistinguishable from a circle
2. it is not differentiable
3. it seems each of its points is rather an angle than a point
4. there is always a point in the lower semicircle between any two given points in the upper semicircle, and conversely.

Has this function been ever described, discussed, named?

Comment: I have no idea what "it seems each of its points is rather an angle than a point;" means.

Comment: I think that is rather similar to the [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function#Dirichlet_function)

Comment: If you think $y = \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ has two values for $x\in \mathbb{R},$ why do you mean that $y = \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ for $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ has only one value?

Comment: More correctly, "$y=\pm\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ is not a function". But if you choose the positive root (which is what you have done since $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is never negative--you indicate the negative root by prefixing a minus sign), it *is* a function (with domain $[-r,r]$).

Comment: @miracle173 - thanks for reformatting the question; I couldn't find how to use the proper mathematical symbols. Yes, it is similar to Dirichlet function. But I am more impressed by it being non-derivable (or could it be said to be derivable in Q but not derivable in R)

Comment: @MPW - Thanks; corrected it in the question.

Comment: And as I indicated, perhaps you need $[-r,r]\cap\mathbb Q$ and $[-r,r]\setminus\mathbb Q$ as the two parts of your domain.

Comment: $f(x)=(2\chi_\mathbb{Q}(x)-1)\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ where $\chi_\mathbb{Q}$ is the Dirichlet function. A worth noting-fact is that (the graphic of) $f$ is dense in the circle. I.E. $\overline{f}=r\mathbb{S}^1$

Comment: @5xum - it is discontinuous at every point, so that each point in the upper hemicircle is immediately followed by a point in the lower hemicircle - an an angle to the straight line between the point and its immediate predecessor.

Comment: @LuísHenrique But a point is still a point, not an angle. Also, saying "each point in the upper hemicircle is immediately followed by a point in the lower hemicircle" is wrong. There is no such thing as "immediatelly followed by" on $\mathbb R$. Can you tell me which point is follows immediatelly after $0.5$?"

Comment: @5xum - No, but there is always an irrational closer to 0.5 than any rational you can think of.

Comment: There's also a rational closer to 0.5 closer to any irrational, so what?

Comment: It would seem this was a bad question, but I have no clue why.

Comment: $x \notin \mathbb Q$ includes $x = 2+3i \in \mathbb C$. I suspect you mean that all x are *real numbers*: $x\in \mathbb R$, such that some are rational number (in $\mathbb Q$) and the others  are irrational real numbers, (in $\mathbb R\setminus Q$),

Comment: To answer your question directly, *yes* I definitely recall seeing this exact function (with $r=1$) presented in an exercise in.a real analysis textbook. The problem asked the student to prove that the function was discontinuous at all points in $(-1,1)$ and continuous at the points $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments,

1. It's not a bad question (in its current form). It shows some serious mathematical misunderstandings, but there's nothing wrong with that on this website, and nothing deserving of downvotes.
2. There is no difficulty or novelty in finding a partition of the reals into two subsets each of which is dense in the reals.
3. Once you have such a partition, there is no difficulty or novelty in using it to define a function whose graph is indistinguishable from some familiar, smooth shape, a function that is not continuous (let alone differentiable) in any open interval.
4. Given the ease of finding such functions, there is probably little interest in describing, discussing, or naming any particular example.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sence now - the function is basically trivial, so there is no reason to discuss it, unless it had some practical application, which probably isn't the case - it it that?

Comment: It's not so much trivial as commonplace – there's nothing to distinguish it from any number of other functions sharing the same properties.